# Does the iSeries Access ODBC Driver support multiple statements in pass-through queries..?

Tags: db2, db2-400

When using the `iSeries Access ODBC Driver` for a Microsoft Access pass-through query, are multiple statements possible..?

This is DB2 for iSeries v7r3m0 and Access 2007, with SQL developed in DBeaver 5.2.5.

All of my previous work has been queries with a single `WITH/SELECT` statement. But this is my first script with multiple statements. Normally I would copy it into an Access pass-through query to make it pretty for my users, but when I try to run this new one, I get the following error:

`ODBC call failed. [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2  for i5/OS]SQL0104 Token ; was not valid. Valid tokens: <END-OF-STATEMENT>`

[image]

The error is clear: it doesn't like the statement terminator character, aka semicolon. If I remove it, the token-of-offense then becomes the following `DECLARE` statement, ad infinitum.

So the obvious question becomes: *can this even be done in an Access pass-through query..?*

I checked the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzaik/connectkeywords.htm) for any connection string keywords that may be of use, but found none.

The general flow of my script is as follows. This works in DBeaver, but not in Access:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE F_CERTOB.NPS_FIRSTDAY NUMERIC(8)
    DEFAULT ( SELECT (YEAR (CURDATE() - 4 MONTHS) * 10000) + 
                     (MONTH(CURDATE() - 4 MONTHS) * 100) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ) ;

DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.NPS_DATA0 
    AS  (   WITH    SOMEDATA    AS  (   SELECT      *
                                        FROM        F_CERTOB.DAILYT
                                        WHERE       DACOMP  = '1'
                                        AND         DAIDAT >= (F_CERTOB.NPS_FIRSTDAY+0)
                                        AND         DAIDAT <= (F_CERTOB.NPS_FIRSTDAY+7)
                                    )
            SELECT  *
            FROM    SOMEDATA
        ) WITH DATA WITH REPLACE ;

WITH    SUMBYINVOICE    AS  (   SELECT      DAACCT, DAIDAT, DAINV#, SUM(DAQTY) AS QTY 
                                FROM        SESSION.NPS_DATA0
                                GROUP BY    DAACCT, DAIDAT, DAINV#
                            )

SELECT      *
FROM        SUMBYINVOICE
WHERE       QTY > 0
ORDER BY    DAACCT, DAIDAT, DAINV# ;

DROP TABLE SESSION.NPS_DATA0 ;
DROP VARIABLE F_CERTOB.NPS_FIRSTDAY ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably sure that you would need to have separate ODBC calls.

Also, unlike Db2 (for LUW) https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html
Db2 for i does not support stand-alone compound SQL, they are only used in SQL procedures. So you can't just wrap a `BEGIN`/`END` around your code.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzcompoundstmt.htm

Still, unless you need the GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE for some performance reason, your could write your code in one statement.

```
WITH F_CERTOB(NPS_FIRSTDAY) AS ( VALUES
    (YEAR (CURDATE() - 4 MONTHS) * 10000) +  (MONTH(CURDATE() - 4 MONTHS) * 100)
)
, NPS_DATA0  AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   F_CERTOB.DAILYT, F_CERTOB
    WHERE  DACOMP  = '1'
    AND    DAIDAT >= (F_CERTOB.NPS_FIRSTDAY+0)
    AND    DAIDAT <= (F_CERTOB.NPS_FIRSTDAY+7)
)
, SUMBYINVOICE AS (
    SELECT      DAACCT, DAIDAT, DAINV#, SUM(DAQTY) AS QTY 
    FROM        NPS_DATA0
    GROUP BY    DAACCT, DAIDAT, DAINV#
)
SELECT      *
FROM        SUMBYINVOICE
WHERE       QTY > 0
ORDER BY    DAACCT, DAIDAT, DAINV#
```

Comment: Well, the sample I provided is quite simplified. The actual script has been an ongoing project for three weeks, with ~300 lines and ~10 DGTTs. It's a report that pulls ~1M rows with some pivoted columns. The script unpivots/repivots twice, to calculate missing data then prioritize some, with a final `EXCEPTION` self-join to find what in the 2nd half isn't in the 1st. As a single `WITH/SELECT`, it got to a point where I killed it after 20 minutes. In came the DGTT's, and now it's only 2 minutes..! And, then the pain of discovering Access won't take it. Boo, lol.

Comment: But I'm currently trying a workaround in Access VBA to send the script through a code-generated dynamic pass-through query to a DB2 `EXEC` statement as a server-side dynamic SQL script. The problem is the Access ODBC engine wants a single statement, so if I can send it as a single EXEC, Access won't care what text is between the quotes, and hopefully with gladly accept whatever rows the statement kicks back. We'll see what happens.

Comment: You should be able to put most of your code in a single table function. The create variable would not be allowed but DGTT’d should be in a MODIFIES SQL DATA table function that you could select from in a single statement from Access